# How to detect a leap year (javascript)

Tags: javascript, oop

The following function is made to detect a leap year which is (on every year that is evenly divisible by 4 - except every year that is evenly divisible by 100 - unless the year is also evenly divisible by 400)

```js
var Year = function(number) {
  this.number = number;
};

Year.prototype.isLeap = function() {
  return this.isDivisibleBy(4) && !this.isDivisibleBy(100) || this.isDivisibleBy(400);
}

Year.prototype.isDivisibleBy = function(divisor) {
  return this.number % divisor === 0;
}

const commonYears = [1700, 1800, 1900, 1999, 2001]
const leapYears = [1600, 2000, 2004, 2008]

commonYears.forEach(y => console.log(y, new Year(y).isLeap()))
leapYears.forEach(y => console.log(y, new Year(y).isLeap()))
```

So if it's a leap year it returns `true` and if not returns `false` but the problem is it always returns `false` even if it's a leap year ***why? and how to fix it***

Comment: I made your code into a runnable snippet but as you can see, it returns `true` for 2000 and `false` for 1999. What years are you using for testing?

Comment: I even tried your code with the exceptions like 1700, 1800 and 1900 and it works just fine

Comment: I was using random years but the problem was forgetting the  parentheses here `Year.prototype.isLeap = function() {
  return ( this.isDivisibleBy(4) && !this.isDivisibleBy(100) ) || this.isDivisibleBy(400);
}`

Comment: I just tried to run the code you edited without the parentheses and it worked fine

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying. Your code appears to work just fine so what were you using to test that was showing only `false`?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use pure functions? You don't need the overhead of objects.

```js
const isDivisibleBy = (number, divisor) => number % divisor === 0;

const isLeapYear = year => isDivisibleBy(year, 4) && !isDivisibleBy(year, 100) || isDivisibleBy(year, 400);

const commonYears = [1700, 1800, 1900, 1999, 2001]
const leapYears = [1600, 2000, 2004, 2008]

commonYears.forEach(y => console.log(y, isLeapYear(y)))
leapYears.forEach(y => console.log(y, isLeapYear(y)))
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're trying to do this Object oriented style do like:

```js
function YearTester(year) {
  this.year = year;
  this.isDivisibleBy = divisor=>{
    return this.year % divisor === 0;
  }
  this.isLeap = ()=>{
    if(this.isDivisibleBy(4)){
      if(this.isDivisibleBy(400) || !this.isDivisibleBy(100)){
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
}
const commonYears = [1700, 1800, 1900, 1999, 2001];
const leapYears = [1600, 2000, 2004, 2008];
const yearTester = new YearTester;
function consoleIt(y){
  yearTester.year = y;
  console.log(y+' is '+(yearTester.isLeap() ? '' : 'not ')+'a leap year');
}
commonYears.forEach(consoleIt);
leapYears.forEach(consoleIt);
```

Your real issue that `if(this.isDivisibleBy(4) && !this.isDivisibleBy(100) || this.isDivisibleBy(4) && this.isDivisibleBy(400))` would have to be in your one liner.